# How to use @ngrx/store in component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

My understanding after reading [the documentation](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors) is that in order to obtain values from an NgRx store, we have to use selectors. So far, I've had luck doing that, only with a small issue regarding typing, which makes me worried if my implementation is incorrect in any way.

So, let's say I want to retrieve a number value from the store, `id` for example. In my componentName.component.ts I would access this value like this:

```js
id$ = this.store.select(selectId);
```

where `selectId` is defined from another file as:

```js
export const selectData = (state: AppState) => state.data;

export const selectId = createSelector(
  selectData,
  (state: DataState) => state.id,
)
```

I am able to access `id$` in my HTML component easily by doing `{{id$ | async}}`, but accessing it from the component class itself has proven a bit more difficult. For starters, the variable type is `Observable<number>` instead of just `number`, and that makes it hard to use it in cases where it needs to be of `number` type, such as when comparing it:

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.id$ === 0);
  }
```

The TypeScript error I get from the code above is:

> TS2367: This condition will always return 'false' since the types
> 'number' and 'Observable ' have no overlap.

And console-logging `id$` itself confirms that it is indeed of `Observable` type, so this leads me to believe I am doing something wrong, but I'm unsure exactly what. Any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: I’d doesn’t seem you have done anything wrong. You just are not familiar with working with observables yet! :-)

Comment: Thank you @BizzyBob , it's great to know there aren't any issues in my code. Your comment encouraged me to have a look at the documentation for Observables and I found this https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable#subscribing-to-observables which is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I also wouldn't suggest you to directly use selectors like that in the component. The general pattern is like this: this.store.pipe(selector).subscribe(value);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`id$` is an `Observable`, and you can access its value by subscribing to it from the component class using `subscribe` function, or from the component template using `async` pipe.

**In Component Class:**

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.id$.subscribe(id => console.log(id));
}
```

**In Component Template:**

```html
<span>{{ id$ | async }}</span>
```

Check the official docs of Angular about `Observable`(s):

https://angular.io/guide/observables